# Drawing transparent rectangle wxWidgets

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, codeblocks, wxwidgets

how is it possible to draw a transparent rectangle using `wxWidgets`, I have tried using transparent brush, but it didn't work , also when I searched I found that anything uses `wxDC` wont support transparent , therefore I have to use `wxGraphicsContext` , but when I tried using it , I got this error `wxGraphicsContext was not declared in this scope`, and it's not going to work on all the `platforms` , so what is the best solution to draw `transparent` `shapes/images` and it will work on most of the `platforms` ?

Answer (score 3):

As you have already discovered, you need to use `wxGraphicsContext` for any non-trivial transparency support (support for it in `wxDC` is limited to drawing bitmaps with alpha channel). Your build of wxWidgets might not include it as it's disabled by default when using MinGW because it doesn't always come with the necessary headers and libraries. If you have them -- and if you're using MinGW-w64 or TDM-GCC, chances are that you do -- you have to explicitly enable GDI+ support when building wxWidgets, either with a `--enable-graphics_ctx` option if you're using configure or by directly editing the `wx/setup.h` file and setting `wxUSE_GRAPHICS_CONTEXT` to 1 in it.